# Conditional Order By on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT year, month, btype, bnumber 
FROM some_table 
ORDER BY year ASC, month ASC, bnumber ASC, btype ASC
```

btype has the following values

```
block
week
month
```

When `btype = block` and `bnumber = 1` I want it to be the first value in the table. But, when `btype = block` and `bnumber = 2` I want it to be after all other `bnumber = 2` values.

here is how the query is currently returning values:

```
year    month   btype   bnumber
======  ======  ======  ======
2017    3       block   1
2017    3       month   1
2017    3       week    1
2017    3       block   2
2017    3       week    2
2017    3       week    3
2017    3       week    4
```

This is how I would like the results to be:

```
year    month   btype   bnumber
======  ======  ======  ======
2017    3       block   1
2017    3       month   1
2017    3       week    1
2017    3       week    2
2017    3       block   2
2017    3       week    3
2017    3       week    4
```

Is something like this possible using CASE? I've tried several different variations but can't seem to get it to work. This is the last statement I tried to attempt to make `btype = block` and `bnumber = 2` be treated as `bnumber = 3` but it didn't work:

```
ORDER BY year ASC, month ASC, 
         CASE btype 
            WHEN 'block' and bnumber = '2' THEN bnumber = '3' 
            ELSE 1 
         END ASC, 
         bnumber ASC, 
         btype ASC
```

Comment: The CASE expression returns a value. It doesn't do an assignment. The expression `bnumber = '3'` is being evaluated as a boolean, i.e. it's doing a comparison, and returning TRUE (1), FALSE (0) or NULL. And the value returned by the CASE expression is what MySQL is ordering.

Comment: **`ORDER BY year, month, bnumber, CASE WHEN btype = 'block'  AND bnumber > 1 THEN 'zzz' ELSE btype END`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT year, month, btype, bnumber
FROM some_table
ORDER BY year ASC, month ASC, 
         CASE 
            -- Place btype ='block' / bnumber = '1' at the first place
            WHEN btype ='block' and bnumber = '1' THEN 1
            -- Prioritize bnumber = '2' / btype <> 'block' over 
            -- bnumber = '2' / btype = 'block'
            WHEN bnumber = '2' THEN CASE 
                                      WHEN btype <> 'block' THEN 1.1
                                      ELSE 1.2
                                    END            
            ELSE bnumber  
         END ASC, 
         bnumber ASC, 
         btype ASC
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0d20c/2)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would satisfy the specification:

```
ORDER
   BY year
    , month
    , bnumber
    , CASE
        WHEN btype = 'block' AND bnumber > 1 
        THEN 'zzz'
        ELSE btype
      END
```

The `CASE` expression is usually going to return the value of `btype`, which is what it looks like we usually want to order on (alphabetically), after ordering on bnumber.

We handle the "special" case of `btype='block' and bnumber>1` ... instead of returning `btype`, we return special a high value 'zzz' that is higher than all other value of btype.

---

A more robust solution would use a separate expression in the ORDR BY, before the `btype` column:

```
ORDER 
   BY year
    , month
    , bnumber
    , CASE
        WHEN btype = 'block' AND bnumber > 1 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END
    , btype
```